# one extra row with one column below the row using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to show a row with information just below each row with multiple columns..I am using jquery datatable. this should look like when we use expand / collapse in datatable.The difference here is the information should show below the rows without clicking on expand button.. I am sending server side request so the data should show without much time delay.

Comment: can any one please help

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking since there is no question, just a vague description of something you want. There is no code and no example to create an answer from, so it is impossible when you are not more concrete. An example, is it the details you are loading serverside or is it both datarows and details?